Is my solution to why no two partitions of equal product exists for the set of nine consecutive integers correct (is there a better approach)?
Show that no set of nine consecutive integers can be partitioned into two sets with
the product of the elements of the first set equal to the product of the elements of
the second set.
Solution: Assume that $$S = \{i,i+1,i+2,i+3,i+4,i+5,i+6, i+7,i+8\}$$ for $i \in 
\mathbb{Z}$
can be partitioned into sets $A$ and $B$ such that the products of the elements are equal = $p$.
Therefore $p$ is divisible by any element of $S$. Hence $p$ is divisble by 7.
$\therefore A$ contains a multiple of 7 and $B$ contains a multiple of $7$. For this to be possible either $i$ and $i+7$ are multiples of 7 or $i+1$ and $i+8$ are multiples of $7$. Hence $i+4$ or $i+5$ is a multiple of $11$. But no other element in $S$ is a multiple of $11$. Therefore either $A$ contains a multiples of $11$ or $B$ contains a multiple of $11$ but not both $A$ and $B$. Hence their products cannot be equal.

Please, use descriptive titles. "Is my solution correct and is there a better more general approach to this problem?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952800/olympiad-problem-erdos-selfridge

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614130/product-of-9-consecutive-numbers-cannot-be-partitioned-into-two-sets-with-equal says the problem has been posted here many times, but doesn't link to any (and doesn't provide a solution).

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897883/the-product-of-consecutive-integers-is-never-a-power-lemma-2-research-paper-st links to a more general result of Erdös and Selfridge (which is probably overkill for the question here).

Also similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382490/is-there-any-elementary-proof-for-the-statement-the-product-of-any-eight-consecu

A paper by Erdös from 1939, proving a product of two or more consecutive integers can never be a square, is freely available at https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1939-03.pdf

The answer to the question in the title, "is there a better approach?" is yes as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704709/given-9-consecutive-naturals-no-partition-into-two-sets-will-give-set-one-produ – it's easier to prove there aren't two partitions with equal product than to prove the product of all nine can't be a square.

Your analysis is invalid.
For example, suppose that $~i~$ is a multiple of $~7.~$
You conclude from this that $~i + 4~$ is a multiple of $~11.~$
Counter example is $~i = 21.$
A more blatant counter example is $~i = 56,~$ since the set $~\{56,57,\cdots,64\},~$ contains no multiple of $~11.~$
This more blatant counter example was constructed by choosing $~i \equiv 0\pmod{7}~$ such that $~i \equiv 1 \pmod{11}.$

Assume that the two partitions do have the same product.
Let $~S~$ denote the set $~\{i,i+1,\cdots,i+8\}.$ 
Let $~t~$ denote $~\displaystyle \prod_{x \in S} x.$
$~0~$ can not be an element in $~S,~$ since otherwise exactly one of the subsets would have a product of $~0.~$
Similarly, $~S~$ can not be all negative numbers, since then, exactly one of the subsets would have a negative product.
Therefore, $~S~$ must be a set of positive integers.
For any prime number $~> 7,~$ you can't have two different elements in $~S~$ both divisible by this prime number.
Therefore, the prime factorization of $~t~$ must have form 
$~2^{2a} \times 3^{2b} \times 5^{2c} \times 7^{2d}.~$
Furthermore, $~S~$ can have at most two different elements both divisible by $~7,~$ and at most two different elements both divisible by $~5.~$
Therefore, $c = 1 = d.$
Similarly, $~S~$ must have exactly $~3~$ elements divisible by $~3,~$ of which at most one of these elements is divisible by $~9.~$
So, you must have $~b = 2.$

Consideration of the prime $~2~$ is trickier.
There must be either $~4~$ or $~5~$ even numbers, of which at least two of these numbers are not divisible by $~4.~$
So, the most you can have is three numbers divisible by $~4,~$ of which at most two of them are divisible by $~8,~$ and at most one of them is divisible by $~16.$
So, if you exclude (one of) the numbers divisible by the highest power of $~2,~$ the product of the remaining even numbers can not be divisible by $~2^8.~$
Therefore, $~a \leq 7.~$
Further, there will be at least $~4~$ even numbers, of which at least one will be divisible by $~8,~$ and one other number will be divisible by $~4.~$
Therefore, $~a \geq 4.~$

In summary, you must have
$$t = 2^a \times 3^b \times 5^c \times 7^d,$$
where $~b = 2,~c = 1 = d,~4 \leq a \leq 7.~$
Therefore, there are only $~4~$ possible products (i.e. values) that the variable $~t~$ can equal.
Therefore, all that you have to do is manually check each of these $~4~$ values, verifying that none of them is the product of $~9~$ consecutive positive integers.
